# How to exclude values from filter in Tableau?

Tags: sql, tableau-api

When creating a filter in Tableau, I am trying to exclude certain values form my dropdown menu.
I have tried editing my filter and excluding the values I do not want to appear in my drop down menu as such:
[image]

The values I have excluded however still apppear in my drop down filter in my dashboard (with a crossed out bar like in the picture I included). Anyone know how to completely exlclude these values from my filter?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check [this](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/hiding-null-values-from-quick-filters)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you show a dropdown filter on a dashboard, it's **linked** to the field on the filter shelf. Therefore, any time you change the filter on the dropdown it changes it in the shelf, and vice-versa.

To remove it from the dropdown, you'll have to create a **copy** of your filtered field (just duplicate it), and have one with the settings you showed here, and the other one to be used in the dropdown.